# How to implement tab bar controller with navigation controller in right way

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, xcode6, uistoryboard

I am using Storyboard and Xcode 6. I have next controllers and scenes in my Storyboard:

`UINavigationController` that has `HomeViewController` as a root. `HomeViewController` has a button that `Show (e.g. Push)` `UITabBarController`. `UITabBarController` has 4 `UIViewControllers`.

But my problem that after I Show `UITabBarController` there are no Navigation Bars in 4 `UIViewControllers`. But I supposed that if I `Show (e.g. Push)` `UITabBarController` then it should has embedded navigation controller that is initial controller in storyboard. Am I right? And if so how can I setup then navigation bar in Storyboard, because there are now default bar event in pushed tab bar that I see on storyboard. I have selected UIViewController and set simulated metrics in identity inspector to Translucent Navigation bar for the Top property, but I supposed it should be automatically added to this controller and to the tab bar without additional steps.

Or should I add new navigation controller for each tab bar items that will have their root view controllers?

The main question why I don't see navigation bar in storyboard using show (e.g. Push). For example if I add navigation controller and then set as root - tab bar controller then Xcode automatically add top navigation bar, but if the queue has an extra step like in my case HomeViewController the top navigation bar never appear automatically.

Answer (score 158, accepted):

Hi you need to embed each view controller that is within the tab bar in a navigation controller of its own. So the flow is like so (HomeVC is embedded in a NavController of it's own):

```
                                         / --> `NavController` --> `ViewController1`
                                         | --> `NavController` --> `ViewController2`
`HomeViewController`-->`TabBarController`|--> `NavController` --> `ViewController3`
                                         \--> `NavController` --> `ViewController4`
```

1. Go to **Editor** --> **Embed In** --> **Tab Bar Controller** (or Navigation Controller)

[image: How to embed correctly]

To answer your questions:

> *Each tab of a tab bar controller interface is associated with a custom (different [sic]) view controller. When the user selects a specific tab, the tab bar controller displays the root view of the corresponding view controller, replacing any previous views.*

So the Root View Controller of the tab must be adjoined to a Navigation Controller; a navigation view controller must be next inline in order for the View Controller to inherit a Navigation. A Tab Bar switches views to whatever is next inline.

This document will help outline more information about it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller

Comment: @Cœur - not broken, just a grammar mistake :-) Thanks for pointing it out. Hope the answer helped you.

Comment: Why is the TabBarController embedded in a navigation controller in this case?

Comment: @themaxgoldman because the OP asked how to show (segue) to a tab bar with nav controllers. So the example does that :-)

Comment: How can we set the title for each controller in tabviewcontroller. Considering that tabviewcontroller is inside the Navigation Controller.

Comment: @NipunArora - the navigation controllers are inside of the tab bar controller. If you are presenting the tab bar controller from a navigation controller you should consider a modal presentation and not a push.

Comment: I had a hard time seeing this on the gif, but the "Is Initial View Controller" checkbox must be checked on the view on the far left, so "HomeViewController" would get the checkbox. [Here is a higher resolution screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDNCF.png) of what I had at the end.

Answer (score 21):

In Swift 2, Xcode 7 has a very handy feature for adding a UINavigationController:

1. Select the UIViewController that is being used as a "tab" for the `UITabBarNavigationController`
2. On the top Xcode menu, select "Editor" ->
3. "Embed In" ->
4. "Navigation Controller"

   [image]

Comment: Actually there is no need to have Xcode 7 or use Swift, since this feature has been in Xcode from the very beginning. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have something like that:

`TabBarController -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller with a Table View -> and from the TableView a MasterDetailView` for example:

I had the problem that there were no Navigation in the MasterDetailView (no Back Button to the ViewController with The TableView).

Workaround is:

Set Segue between TableView and MasterDetailView to:
[Kind: Push (Deprecated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTKLT.png)

Run your app...hopefully you will see the Back Button...change the Kind to `Show (e.g. Push)`, run again -> it should work.