# How to embed UITabBarController inside UINavigationController?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I want to embed a `UITabBarController` inside a `UINavigationController`.  I found [a similar question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422054/how-to-implement-tab-bar-controller-with-navigation-controller-in-right-way), but my attempted implementation does not let me add a `UIBarButtonItem` to `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems`.

Below is a screenshot of my implementation.  "Button 1" and "Button 2" are not displayed in the running app.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

[image: UITabBarController inside UINavigationController screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your "Button 1" and "Button 2" are not visible because there are overlapped by the navigation bar of the root navigation controller.
So you can do the following:
Step 1. Create a `UITabBarController` subclass and assign it in IB to your tab bar controller.
Step 2. In `-viewWillAppear:` method just hide navigation bar of root navigation controller

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
}
```

Step 3: Bring back navigation bar when you go back to root view

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];
}
```