# How to load another View Controller on Tabbed application Without losing the tab

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I have a Tab Bar application coded in Objective-c. One of the tabviews I have is a TableView. What I'm trying to do is, when a cell of this TableView is selected, the app takes the user to another view, but this view isn't on the tab menu, and I don't want to lose the tab menu when this view appears.

Is it possible to do it? How? Couldn't find much on the web.

Comment: you want to show UIView in same UIViewController?

Comment: you need to use container view! or build your own tab bar controller !

Comment: I would like to show a UIViewController but don't want to lose the tabbar

Comment: If you put the view controller with the table view into a navigation controller, you can push a controller with the new view.

Comment: 2 options either push a new UiViewcontroller on top assuming that you have a UINavigationController in that Tab. or present a Modal View Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just embed navigation controller to that tab's viewcontroller which have tableview.

so your viewhierarchy should be like tabbar controller - navigation controller - viewcontroller (tab) - detailviewcontroller

you can embed navigation controller by selecting viewcontroller, then from menu select editor then embed in then navigation controller.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: How do I link the viewcontroller(tab) to detailviewcontroller? I clicked on the viewcontroller(tab) held "control"dragged to the detailviewcontroller and selected (show detail) but it replaced the entire tabbar

Comment: I did it! instead of selecting "show detail"you have to select "show"" 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

> If you are having the single View Controller to show then you can try doing this by **adding the new view controller's view as
>   subView** to the current view controller's view

Eg:

```
newVC.view.frame = self.view.frame;
newVC.view.frame.size.height = self.view.frame.size.height - HEIGHT_OF_TAB_BAR;
[self.view addSubview:newVC.view];
```

> If there are more View Controller's that are adding further then
>   using the navigation controller under tab bar controller will also
>   work.

Refer: [How to implement tab bar controller with navigation controller in right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422054/how-to-implement-tab-bar-controller-with-navigation-controller-in-right-way)