# Navigation Bar goes beneath Status Bar in iOS application

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I have a Table View, Navigation Bar and Left Bar Button as following image:
[image]

When I run the application, the Navigation Bar goes under Status Bar as following image:

[image]

Is there's any fix for this?

I am coding using swift 2.0 and Xcode 7.3.1

Comment: Are you using a `UINavigationController`?

Comment: Try to remove the `navigationController` and embed it again.

Comment: @Code, I am using Tab Bar Controller.

Comment: @NiravDoctorwala, I did that, but same problem.

Comment: The second image and first image are matched with together(Check the vertical space between battery icon and you 'logout' button- the gap is same). The only diffrence is that in the xib file you can not see the career icon and clock but in emulator and real device you can see them too.

Comment: If you want to use navigation controller and tab bar controller together you should embed tab bar in a navigation controller. Do you do this? Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27425271/1939409

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad, Yes, that's worked! and thanks for the link :)

Comment: You are welcome. I post it as an answer so you can accept it to more clearly help other readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use navigation controller and tab bar controller together you should embed tab bar in a navigation controller.

Please see below stack post:

[Using tabbar and navigation bar together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27425271/1939409)

Answer (score 0):

it is better to add navigation bar to your table view..
You can set it via going in embed in - navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the nav bar according to safe area.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding following line in viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
```