# How to have a UIViewController in all views but not related to all views

Tags: ios, swift

Using swift I have my IOS application's UITabBarController set up like so

Home | Profile | Create

Now I have other views that are not related to the views on the UITabBarController like a (View with A photo with a description).

So say I go to add the UITabBarController to the (View with a photo with description)

Xcode would then change my UITabBarController like so

Home | Profile | Create | (View with a photo with description)

when I want the tab bar to still be at the bottom of my (View with a photo with description) but to stay like

Home | Profile | Create

I still want to have The UITabBarController at the bottom of this view and every other view.

I can't figure out how to do this without the UITabBarController forcing the view to have a relationship with it.

Comment: perhaps this might help you if I understand your question correctly https://www.raywenderlich.com/113388/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1

Comment: I think you need to work on your terminology a bit, its quite hard to understand what you are asking. Are you looking to know how to click a button inside "home" and have it move to another screen while keeping the tabbar along the bottom?

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin maybe my edit helps i'm lost

Comment: @Asdrubal maybe my edit helps

Comment: Not a lot, i think I would ask my question again. To be clear, the UIViewController is the top most element, it manages a view. In most cases I think you are using the word view, when in fact you mean UIViewController. Based on your edit I think you need to learn more about navigation and presenting viewControllers. I think you are either looking for information on how to present a viewController modally, so it displays over everything and not tied to a tab. Or else you want each of your tabs to be a UINavigationController so that you can push another viewController onto the stack at will

Comment: hopefully that will give you more information to google for a tutorial. Perhaps @Asdrubal 's link might be useful for you

Comment: I agree with @SimonMcLoughlin about using UINavigationController. If you look at the link I posted above and the following link I am posting here you can get an idea of how to use the navigation controller with the tab bar controller [TabBar & Navigation Controller in Storyboard](http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/BeginningStoryboard.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as other guys, it is really hard to understand your question. But if you want to add a new tab bar controller within one existing tab, you can simply use container to achieve it, as in the following figure.

[image]

Comment: If u have any query, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make your (View with a photo with description) reachable from one of your other views (Home | Profile | Create), such as the user taps a photo on Home view and your (View with a photo with description) appears.

After that, you can embed the view from which you reach to photo with description view (from what I think, it might be Home view) into a navigation controller. By this way, Tab Bar Controller will have relationship with navigation controller and any view controlled by said navigation controller will inherit the tab bar from it. You might want to check the answer on this page for further information: [How to implement tab bar controller with navigation controller in right way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422054/how-to-implement-tab-bar-controller-with-navigation-controller-in-right-way)