# Edit button inside UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I just embedded my UINavigationController into a UITabBarController. I can no longer see my view title or edit button. Please see storyboard below. How do I make the edit button visible again?

My Storyboard:
[image: My Storyboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than the following organization (which you're currently using):

```
NavController -> TabBarController -> ViewControllerA
                                  \
                                   -> ViewControllerB
```

You must do the following:

```
TabBarController -> NavControllerA -> ViewControllerA
                 \
                  -> NavControllerB -> ViewControllerB
```

`UITabBarController`s should always be the root view. Each child view controller needs its own navigation controller to achieve the navigation bar + tab bar effect you desire. Here is an example of what the structure should look like:

[image: Storyboard laid out with TabBarController at the root.]

As for adding navigation items / titles to each view controller once you've done the above, make sure to drag Navigation Items onto each view controller. You can find the Navigation Item in the Object Library at the bottom of the Utilities view:

[image: Navigation Item in the Object Library]

Comment: When I was first learning how to embed into a UITabBarController, I was told I had to have the NavController out front. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40509479/7100251

Comment: That may work in some cases, but you'll end up encountering weird errors (like the one you're encountering). UINavigationControllers are designed to be embedded in UITabBarControllers, not the other way around. There is a similar question and answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422054/how-to-implement-tab-bar-controller-with-navigation-controller-in-right-way

Comment: I tried that approach, but it only cut off more from the top of my view controllers.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean by that. You may be encountering a different problem setting up your view controllers like I have outlined above. You could give me a link to your project and I could try fixing it. Or you could open another question for the cut off issue.

Comment: How can I give you a link to my project? It is in XCode.

Comment: You can create a public repository on GitHub and share the link here. Or zip up your project and upload it to a file hosting site like Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Ah, you'll need to compress your entire project directory rather than just the xcodeproj file (compress the folder that contains the xcodeproj file and all your other files).

Comment: I've updated the question to include adding a navigation item. I also took a look at your project and fixed up the storyboard: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5xMSwZtXPBHM1hiUmhsWUpTbkk

Comment: Is there any way you could attach a picture of it? For some reason I cannot open it.

Comment: If you take a look at the actual storyboard file, I believe Drive adds a .xml to the end. Try removing that extension and just use .storyboard.

Comment: The file is not compatible. I need to update to Xcode 8 but my computer will not allow it. Anyway you could send a screenshot?

Comment: Updated the answer with a screenshot of the reorganization I did.