# Using UITabBarController with UINavigationController - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am making an app which requires a use of a `UITabBarController` along with `UINavigationController`. I have made the following flow in storyboard.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLz0B.jpg)

Now the first question is that is this accepted by Apple, as there are too many discussions for the same.

The other matter of concern is that is it possible to eliminate any `UINavigationController` and still get the same flow of the app? The main thing required is to have the SAME tab bar and navigation bar on all sub tabs of the tabs. One point to be noted is that if I remove the second `UINavigationController` then my app navigates directly from sub tab to home view controller on clicking back button.

I have been stuck on this since hours now. I am new to iOS app development and have never uploaded any app to the app store. Any help would greatly valued.

EDIT :

I put the second navigation controller as shown in the answers - [see this flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQISl.jpg), But because I have a navigation controller before the HomeViewController, so I am getting a navigation bar at the top and then some empty space below that(exactly equal to the top navigation bar) and then the page contents on runtime. Any solution to this?

Comment: this drawers... only way is to use one main view with tabbar in container and that drawer, navigation etc on top. And again why apple could possibly not accept app? O.o

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422054/how-to-implement-tab-bar-controller-with-navigation-controller-in-right-way

Comment: @AvijitNagare Thanks for the link :)

Comment: @AvijitNagare  
I did the same as shown in link but because I have a navigation controller before the HomeViewContreoller, so i am getting a navigation bar at the top and then some empty space below that(exactly equal to the top navigation bar) and then the page contents on runtime. Any solution to this?

Comment: Yes, correct. it will remain same when you embed into NavC. you can set it to none from attribute inspector by selecting NavC. or hide by programatically. or try for custom navigation library.

Comment: @AvijitNagare I tried setting none the second navigation controller but then the navigation bar back button from the sub tab takes me directly to the home view controller

Comment: Dont push tab bar controller from HomeViewController. either [self presentviewcontroller] or [self setViewController:tabViewController]

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean by this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is acceptable by Apple.

But View hierarchy is not managed correctly. In your case Tab bar will be the root view controller for 2nd navigation controller.

Also, Tab and sub tab you are pushing will be part of 2nd navigation controller.

That's the reason you are getting back on Home view controller.

It's good practice to keep navigation controller to each Tab to manage it's sub-tab hierarchy.

You could present tab bar controller or setviewcontroller from Home View controller.

Comment: so you mean the flow will be like tab bar controller > navigation controller > tab1; same tab bar controller > other navigation controller > tab2 ,and so on?

Comment: @user7205816. correct. so each tab nav. con. will manage its own stack.

Comment: But I am getting empty space below navigation bar (see edited question), and if i set the second navigation controller's bar to none then when we click on back button from sub tab it jumps to home view controller

Answer (score 0):

First embed tab bar controller as in this image[image] and the embed navigation bar controller as in this image [image] finally this will look like [image]

Comment: but in this case i will need to embed navigation controller in all the 4 tabcontroller pages right?

Comment: I did the same as shown by you but because I have a navigation controller before the HomeViewContreoller, so i am getting a navigation bar at the top and then some empty space below that(exactly equal to the top navigation bar) and then the page contents on runtime. Any solution to this?

Comment: But I am getting empty space below navigation bar (see edited question), and if i set the second navigation controller's bar to none then when we click on back button from sub tab it jumps to home view controller