# Pop view segue in Xcode

Tags: ios, segue

I have 2 UIViewControllers with their own navigation bars, but they're not embedded in a Navigation Controller. I want the bar button item of the first view to push the second view, and a bar button on the second view to pop the view, showing the first view underneath.

I've added a show segue from the first view to the second one in my storyboard but I can't find a pop segue when I try add a segue between the second view's bar button back to the first view. Here's what my storyboard looks like:

[image: storyboard]

How would I make the back button on the second view pop itself to show the first view?

Comment: Why don't you just embed navigation controller with only first controller.Then add a bar button item on your first view controller navigation bar . Then give a segue from that bar button to second controller.

Comment: The first view controller is already embedded in a tab bar controller. I didn't want to over complicate things.

Comment: You can still embed navigation controller with tab bar as well.There will be no complications with that.

Comment: check this-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422054/how-to-implement-tab-bar-controller-with-navigation-controller-in-right-way.This shows how to add navigation controller with tab bar.