# How to show UITabBar after segue on child ViewController?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, segue, childviewcontroller

I have 4 main `ViewController`s that are connected to a `UITabBarController`. These are the 4 main screens of my application. Each of these 4 screens has an icon on the `TabBar`.

Now, from within one of these main screens, I want to be able to click a button to show a new "child" view controller. When I segue from the `MainVC` to the `ChildVC,` the `UITabBar` does not show on the `ChildVC`. How can I get the `UITabBar` to remain shown? I do not want to add the `ChildVC` to the `UITabBar`, as it should not have an icon on the bar.

I am open to using any type of segue or combination of views.

Within `MainVC`, I want to click a button to show `ChildVC` WITHOUT losing the `UITTabBar` from the `MainVC` (and without adding `ChildVC` as an icon to `UITabBar`).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question's hypothesis correctly, you should stack all 4 “main screens” into separate navigation stacks (UINavigationController).

So the outcome would be:

```
UITabBarController -> UINavigationController -> UIViewController (1 of those main screens) click button -> Desired UIViewController
```

Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27425271/8290785

Comment: It works! You are my hero. (I've been trying custom segues and container views for hours - nothing worked. Thank you!)

Comment: @purebreadd you are very welcome :) please mark as correct answer